# Is there a way to run integration tests in Jenkins build concurrently in multiple nodes

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, integration-testing, continuous-testing

Is there a way to run 100s of automated tests in Jenkins build across multiple slaves concurrently? My Jenkins setup has 300+ automated tests and has access to 6-7 nodes. So when I ran my Jenkins job, is there way to distribute the load of 300+ tests across available 6-7 nodes and execute them simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are these tests arranged? If you mean that you have a single Jenkins job with 300+ stages where each stage is an automated test, then you can start by setting the Jenkins agent to `none`:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    ....
```

This will force you to set the agent on which each of those 300+ stages run. So at the start of each stage, you can set the node on which it should run:

```
stage("build and test the project") {
    agent any
    stages {
        ....
```

You can then configure your node to use the allocation method as "Use this node as much as possible".

Of course if your build setup is different, you will have to use a different configuration.